# How can I reduce the total amount of frames in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running a tracking program but it is taking too long with the amount of frames in the video.

I want to reduce the total number of frames in my AVI videos to 1/15th of the original file. Not frames per second. How can I do this?

Comment: To Paul (and maybe to the anonymous user...) claim your account and join this community: you can modify your question, upvote the answers you find correct, choose the better one, help other and receive help... `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you meant   - "**to** *1/15th of the original*".

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='not(mod(n,15))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4
```

Comment: I think you have seen (correctly) beyond the preposition. To me it makes sense even __by__ (To shrink 15 Mb in 1 Mb it seems to me to ask a lot, to shrink 15 MB in 14 is more _proposable_).